# How do you create a permanent oauth invite for your discord bot?

Tags: javascript, html, oauth, discord

I have a webpage setup for my discord bot and I created an invite button for my bot which contains the oauth link. However, it only works once and says "No scopes provided".
[image]

Here is my oauth link [url](https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=859544628285407253&permissions=8&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdiscord.com%2Fapi%2Foauth2%2Fauthorize%3Fclient_id%3D859544)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an OAuth2 URL for your discord bot, I'd recommend [this guide](https://discordjs.guide/preparations/adding-your-bot-to-servers.html#creating-and-using-your-invite-link), but here's a basic run-down.

1. Ensure that you have a bot created and linked to the application

[image: Discord Developer "Bot" Page, with "Add Bot" button highlighted.]

2. Select `OAuth2` from the sidebar.

[image: Discord Developer Sidebar, with "OAuth2" option highlighted.]

3. Scroll down to the "OAuth2 URL Generator" section, and enable the `bot` scope. (Don't worry about adding a redirect URL, you won't need it for this.)

[image: Discord OAuth2 URL Generator Scopes Panel, with the "Bot" option highlighted.]

4. Scroll down further again, and select the required permissions for your bot.

[image: Discord OAuth2 Bot Permissions Panel, with "Administrator" Enabled.]

5. Click the "Copy" button to copy your invite URL

[image: Discord OAuth2 URL Generator Scopes Panel, with the "Copy" button highlighted.]

This URL doesn't expire, meaning it will work so long as the application (and bot) still exist.

With that said, [here's a fixed version of your OAuth URL](https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=859544628285407253&permissions=8&scope=bot).